# Leaflet ( Leaflet.Photo ) to show geotagged photos

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet, photos

I'm pretty new in web technologies and I'm having an issue with placing/inserting geotagged photos into the openstreetmap. In a script.js I do:

```
var map = L.map( map_div, {
        center: [20.0, 5.0],
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoom: 3
});

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
            subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4']
}).addTo( map );

                 // here is my problem
var photoLayer = L.Photo.Cluster( { spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1.2 }).on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template('<img src="{url}"/></a><p>{caption}</p>', evt.layer.photo), {
        className: 'leaflet-popup-photo',
        minWidth: 400
        }).openPopup();
});


var photos = [];
photos.push({
        lat: map_lat, // longitude
        lng: map_lon, // latitude
        thumbnail: path // path to my photo
});

photoLayer.add(photos).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(photoLayer.getBounds());
```

And my browser ( Chromium ) is still complaining like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Cluster' ofundefined
(anonymous function) @ script.js:71m.
Callbacks.j @ jquery.min_1.11.3.js:2m.
Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min_1.11.3.js:2
x @ jquery.min_1.11.3.js:5
m.ajaxTransport.a.send.b @ jquery.min_1.11.3.js:5
```

Don't you guys, please, have any idea why i cannot put the photos to the map?

**ANSWER:** Problem solved by correcting case in call function L.Photo.Cluster -> L.photo.cluster and another issue was in importing JS files, correct sequence of imports there:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/gh-pages/examples/lib/cluster/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/gh-pages/examples/lib/cluster/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/gh-pages/Leaflet.Photo.js"></script>
    <script src="MYscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question from me: did you import `Leaflet.Photo.js` script before calling `var photoLayer = L.Photo.Cluster(...`?

Comment: @ghybs Yes I did in head section of index.php file like: <script type="application/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/gh-pages/Leaflet.Photo.js"></script>

Comment: Thx for the confirmation! If Tomislav's answer did not resolve your issue, I would suggest you open the Developers Tools (hit F12 on most browsers) and inspect what the console tells you.

Comment: Once you correct the capitalization, all looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/31/

Comment: @ghybs This is what I did first and console is saying exactly what i wrote in my question. As I said I'm kind of beginner in web developing so I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: BTW, are you testing from local file or on a server? In former case, make sure to correct your path to "Leaflet.Photo.js" file with `http://rawgit.com/…`, otherwise `//raw…` will try to read from your local files (it will try using the same protocol).

Comment: True, sorry I did not pay enough attention about the console :)

Comment: @ghybs I'm testing from local file and path to "Leaflet.Photo.js" is like; src="//rawgit.com/....", I'm pretty sure it is caused because of the path to my local file.

Comment: I think there is a high chance your page fails loading the plugin. Console should report a 404 error. Have you tried appending `http:` before `//rawgit.com`?

Comment: @ghybs I tried right now but still the same and I'm event using your code to test it right now.. Do I have to write before src="" type="application/javascript" everywhere? I'm getting no 404 error

Comment: You do not even have to specify `type="application/javascript"`. Very strange… Please make sure also that you import "Leaflet.markercluster", but even if you were not, the error report would have been different…

Comment: I see that you use jQuery, maybe there is some extra code that needs debugging as well. Any chance you could reproduce your issue online (e.g. on jsfiddle)?

Comment: @ghybs Yes I did import "Leaflet.markercluster", I don't know what is wrong.. Firefox is saying isnted of something about cluster this: TypeError: L.photo is undefined. But I thought L.photo is declared in imported files.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to. At this point the only thing that I can think of is if your "script.js" (where you call `var photoLayer = L.Photo.Cluster(...`) is placed **before** "Leaflet.Photo.js"… (it should be **after** importing all libraries)

Comment: @ghybs Yes my friend, it was because of the sequence of imports. Man, I'm really thankful for your time and I really appreciate it. Thank you again!

Comment: yw :) Please can you kindly post an answer with your finding and accept it, so that other people know that your question is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at docs of plugin in question it seems to be a simple case sensitivity issue, correct would be:

```
 L.photo.cluster( <insert code here> )
```

https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/blob/gh-pages/examples/picasa.html

Comment: good idea but almost the same result: browser is saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cluster' of undefined"